# robots.txt URL patterns with @@

Tags: robots.txt

I want to disallow `/book-search` and currently there is a rule in robots.txt like below:

```
Disallow: /@@book-search*
```

When I try with Webmasters Tool robots.txt tester, it says `/book-search` is still allowed.

Is it because of `@@`? What is the meaning of `@@`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@@` has no reserved meaning in the [robots.txt specification](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html).

So a line like `Disallow: /@@example` will disallow crawling of URLs whose path literally starts with `/@@example`, e.g.:

```
http://example.com/@@example
http://example.com/@@example.html
http://example.com/@@example/foo
```

If you want to disallow crawling of URLs whose path starts with `/book-search`, then you should use:

```
Disallow: /book-search
```

([without a trailing `*`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/75997/17633))

This will disallow crawling, for example:

```
http://example.com/book-search
http://example.com/book-search.html
http://example.com/book-search/
http://example.com/book-search/results
```

Comment: Thanks ! Is `*` working with `User-agent: Googlebot` ? eg. `Disallow: /book-search*` If we put `Disallow: /book-search` will it disallow `/book-search/search-from-author` ?

Comment: @Elike: Yes, as you can see in the last example of my answer. `Disallow` always takes the **beginning** of a URL path. So `Disallow: /a` blocks everything that *starts with* "/a": `/a`, `/ab`, `/a.b`, `/a/b`, … (And yes, Google supports `*` as wildcard in `Disallow` values, but, again, it’s not needed in your case.)